# EOFError when executing Python script using stream redirection

Tags: python, eof, eoferror

I keep getting the EOF error when I execute the Python script using stream redirection.

**Script**

```
name=input('Enter your name : ')
print ('Welcome ' + name)
input('Press \'ENTER\' to exit!')
```

**Execution command:**

```
helloworld.py < input.dat
```

**Error:**

```
Enter your name : Welcome Gunit
Press 'ENTER' to exit!Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Reference\Python\Codes\helloworld.py", line 28, in <module>
    input('Press \'ENTER\' to exit!')
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Hi Gunit. Since the below answer did seem to solve your problem, can you mark the answer as accepted? That would remove this question from the "unanswered questions" list. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code reads two lines from the file (one for the name, and one for the "Enter to exit"). Your input file only has one line in it.

Therefore, Python reaches the End-Of-File indication before it can read the 2nd line.

To fix, ensure that your `input.dat` has at least two lines, or delete the 2nd `input()` call.

Comment: thanks... it worked... I had 2 lines in input.dat, but the 2nd line had no character to be read by input()...